# Using fsspec at pandas.DataFrame.to_csv command

Tags: python, pandas, ssh, fsspec

I want to write the csv-file from pandas dataframe on remote machine connecting via smtp-ssh.
Does anybody know how add "storage_options" parameter correctly?

Pandas documentation says that I have to use some dict as parameter's value. But I don't understand which exactly.

```
hits_df.to_csv('hits20.tsv', compression='gzip', index='False', chunksize=1000000, storage_options={???})
```

Every time I got `ValueError: storage_options passed with file object or non-fsspec file path`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Pandas is supporting *fsspec* which lets you work easily with remote filesystems, and abstracts over *s3fs* for Amazon S3 and *gcfs* for Google Cloud Storage (and other backends such as (S)FTP, SSH or HDFS). In particular s3fs is very handy for doing simple file operations in S3 because boto is often quite subtly complex to use.

The argument `storage_options` will allow you to expose *s3fs* [arguments](https://s3fs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#credentials) to pandas.

You can specify an AWS Profile manually using the `storage_options` which takes a dict. An example bellow:

```python
import boto3

AWS_S3_BUCKET = os.getenv("AWS_S3_BUCKET")
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.getenv("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID")
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.getenv("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY")
AWS_SESSION_TOKEN = os.getenv("AWS_SESSION_TOKEN")

df.to_csv(
    f"s3://{AWS_S3_BUCKET}/{key}",
    storage_options={
        "key": AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
        "secret": AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
        "token": AWS_SESSION_TOKEN,
    },
)
```

Comment: Maybe something has changed since this answer was written, but in aiobotocore v2.5.4 (which is what s3fs/fsspec uses internally) the arguments are not called `key` and `token` secret` but rather, same as the AWS environment variables, `aws_access_key_id` and `aws_secret_access_key`. Using the code in this answer would create the error “AioSession._create_client() got an unexpected keyword argument 'key'”.

Answer (score 0):

You will find the set of values to use by experimenting directly with the implementation backend [SFTPFileSystem](https://filesystem-spec.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#fsspec.implementations.sftp.SFTPFileSystem). Whatever kwargs you use these are the same ones that would go into `stoage_options`. Short story: paramiko is not the same as command-line SSH, so some trialing will be required.

If you have things working via the file system class, you can use the alternative route

```
fs = fsspec.implementations.sftp.SFTPFileSystem(...)
# same as fs = fsspec.filesystem("ssh", ...)
with fs.open("my/file/path", "rb") as f:
    pd.read_csv(f, other_kwargs)
```

Answer (score -1):

If you do not have cloud storage access, you can access public data by specifying an anonymous connection like this

```
pd.read_csv('name',<other fields>, storage_options={"anon": True})
```

Else one should pass `storage_options` in dict format, you will get `name` and `key` by your cloud VM host (including Amazon S3, Google Cloud, Azure, etc.)

```
pd.read_csv('name',<other fields>, \
           storage_options={'account_name': ACCOUNT_NAME, 'account_key': ACCOUNT_KEY})
```

Comment: I tried again with

hits_df.to_csv('ssh://srv0.ecom.ftt.local/hits20.tsv',
               compression='gzip', index='False', chunksize=1000000,
               storage_options={'password': '***', 'port':22, 'username': '****'})

and got "OSError: Socket is closed". However, I can connect via console using common "ssh -i ***@srv0.ecom.ftt.local"